# I don't have upstart installed on 16.04 but /etc/init has a bunch of .conf scripts in it. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, upstart

I'm trying to get a command to run on boot and wrote an upstart .conf file and put it into /etc/init.  It's a brand new EC2 instance and theres was already bunch of .conf files there.  My file wasn't working and I found out that upstart is NOT installed.

Why are there files in /etc/init if there's no upstart? Also, what's the preferred way to run a command on boot in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429032/ .

Answer (score 3):

Upstart was replaced by `systemd` in April 2015 (v15.04).<sup>1</sup> There are still many files flying around for compatibility reasons.

See also:

- [How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts)
- [What are the pros/cons of Upstart and systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-upstart-and-systemd)
- [How to find out if a system uses SysV, Upstart or Systemd initsystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196166/how-to-find-out-if-a-system-uses-sysv-upstart-or-systemd-initsystem)

<sub>1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd</sub>